# Retornar datos en consulta que no cumple el inner join con LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy intentando retornar datos en una consulta realizada con LinQ, el problema que tengo es que las tablas consultadas no siempre tendrán datos, entonces debo realizar un left join.

El método que tengo actualmente es:

```
public TemplateWorks GetTemplate(int id)
{
    return GetIQueryable()
        .Include(x => x.Trabajos)
        .Include(z => z.Trabajos.Empleados).DefaultIfEmpty()
        .Include(y => y.Trabajos.Tareas).DefaultIfEmpty()
        .Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Como podemos ver en la consulta la tabla "Trabajos" siempre tendrá datos, en cambio "Empleados" y "Tareas" no siempre tendrán. Mi duda es como retornar datos de estas dos ultimas tablas, aun cuando alguna de ellas no los tenga ya que internamente veo que realizan un inner join.

La consulta en sql server es la siguiente:

```
SELECT *
FROM Template A
INNER JOIN Trabajos B ON A.IdTrabajo = B.Id
LEFT JOIN Empleados C ON B.Id = C.IdTrabajo
LEFT JOIN OTS.Tareas D ON D.IdTrabajo = B.ID
WHERE A.IdTrabajoLinkeado = 125287
```

Por su ayuda muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PAra hacer left join en las tablas con EntityFramework trabajo de la siguiente manera

```
var Datos = (from A in Context.Template
             join B in Context.Trabajos on A.IdTrabajo equals B.Id
             join Aux1 in Context.Empleados on B.Id equals Aux1.IdTrabajo into Left1
             from C in Left1.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join Aux2 in Context.Empleados on B.Id equals Aux2.IdTrabajo into Left2
             from OTS in Left2.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { A, B, C, D }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Espero te ayude esta sentencia